# WinObjC orientation issue

Tags: winobjc

I'm trying to convert an iOS project to Windows 10, it compiles and links successfully, the binary starts, but the app is not well oriented: my app is in landscape on iPad, but on Windows 10 all the UI is rotated by 90°...

I've no idea on how to fix that.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in new verison of #WinObjC